# How can I convert a list of rules into a list of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, rule, conversion

How can I convert a list of solutions to a list of equations? For example, say I have:

```
sol = {{a->1},{b->2}}
```

and I would like to change it to

```
sol2 = {a == 1,b == 2}
```

I tried without success the following:

```
{{a -> 1}, {b -> 2}} /. {RightArrow -> Equal}
```

Comment: `a->1` has a full form of `Rule[a,1]`, so the `RightArrow` replacement doesn't replace anything.  Try `Rule -> Equal`

Comment: @JasonB. That works! Thanks!

Comment: When having a problem with replacement, look at the `FullForm` of the expression. It is that form that is being acted on.

Comment: @BobHanlon Great advice, thanks! I didn't know!